# Call has possible formatting directive

Tags: go

When I run this code

```
package main
import ("fmt")
func main() {
    i := 5
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground %d",i)
}
```

([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/0Dhuhi8trQK))

I get the following warning:

```
prog.go:5: Println call has possible formatting directive %d
Go vet exited.
```

What is a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

[`fmt.Println`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) doesn't do formatting things like `%d`. Instead, it uses the default format of its arguments, and adds spaces between them.

```
fmt.Println("Hello, playground",i)  // Hello, playground 5
```

If you want printf style formatting, use [`fmt.Printf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf).

```
fmt.Printf("Hello, playground %d\n",i)
```

And you don't need to be particular about the type. `%v` will generally figure it out.

```
fmt.Printf("Hello, playground %v\n",i)
```

Comment: Ironically the learn go tour uses `%g` in a `fmt.Println` statement https://go.dev/tour/basics/2

Answer (score 19):

The warning is telling you you have a formatting directive (`%d` in this case) in a call to `Println`. This is a warning because `Println` *does not support formatting directives*. These directives are supported by the formatted functions `Printf` and `Sprintf`. This is explained thoroughly in the [`fmt` package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt).

As you can plainly see when you run your code, the output is

```
Hello, playground %d 5
```

Because `Println` does what its docs say - it prints its arguments followed by a line break. Change that to `Printf`, which is likely what you intended, [and you get this instead](https://play.golang.org/p/6apmsKPiPkf):

```
Hello, playground 5
```

Which is presumably what you intended.

Answer (score -4):

```html
package main
import ("fmt")
func main() {
    i := 5
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground %d",i)
}
===================================================
package main
import ("fmt")
func main() {
    i := 5
    fmt.Printf("Hello, playground %d",i)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Why duplicate the code? Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.