# go test won't build: Call has possible formatting directive

Tags: go

`go test` refuses to build when a call to a function in the library to be tested *by design* contains a formatting directive. Is this intentional or is this a bug? Either way, is there a workaround?

Please note, unlike [Call has possible formatting directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53961617/call-has-possible-formatting-directive), this is *not* a call to a built-in function that doesn't accept formatting directives. It is a call to a function that I wrote and which is specifically designed to accept formatting directives.

Here is a contrived but complete reproduction. Note `makeError` is designed to handle a format string. `go build` works fine, but `go test` produces the following error and does not run any tests:

```
.\example.go:16:13: makeError call has possible formatting directive %v
FAIL    sandbox/example [build failed]
```

go version: `go version go1.12.7 windows/amd64`

`example.go`:

```golang
package example

import "fmt"

type ErrExample struct {
    data interface{}
    msg  string
}

func (e *ErrExample) Error() string {
    return e.msg
}

func Divide(f1 float64, f2 float64) (float64, error) {
    if f2 == 0.0 {
        return 0, makeError(nil, "Cannot divide %v by 0", f1)
    }
    return f1 / f2, nil
}

func makeError(data interface{}, msgAndArgs ...interface{}) error {
    msg := ""
    switch len(msgAndArgs) {
    case 0:
        // Ignore
    case 1:
        msg = fmt.Sprint(msgAndArgs[0])
    default:
        if str, ok := msgAndArgs[0].(string); ok {
            msg = fmt.Sprintf(str, msgAndArgs[1:]...)
        }
        msg = fmt.Sprint(msgAndArgs...)
    }
    return &ErrExample{data: data, msg: msg}
}
```

`example_test.go`:

```golang
package example

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestDivide(t *testing.T) {
    _, err := Divide(1230, 0)
    if err == nil {
        t.Errorf("Expected error when dividing by 0")
    }
}
```

Comment: `msg = fmt.Sprint(msgAndArgs...)` - should this not be wrapped in an `else` block?

Comment: *"is there a workaround?"* try using the -vet=off flag. Why? This is a `go vet` error from the `printf` check and `go test` runs `go vet` before executing the test binary. https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages and https://golang.org/cmd/vet/.

Comment: Or slightly less sledge-hammery: [`-printfuncs=makeError`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12294) ([additional explanation](https://kuzminva.wordpress.com/2017/11/07/go-vet-printf-family-check/))

Comment: @MTCoster will that flag be passed by `go test` to `go vet`?

Comment: @mkopriva Good point, I wasn't thinking about that. Worth a quick test I think

Comment: @MTCoster alas the printfuncs flag doesn't even seem to work with `go vet`. Full info is outside the scope of this question

Comment: @mkopriva solution helps me, +1

Answer (score 7):

From the help text of go test:

> As part of building a test binary, go test runs go vet on the package
>   and its test source files to identify significant problems. If go vet
>   finds any problems, go test reports those and does not run the test
>   binary. Only a high-confidence subset of the default go vet checks are
>   used. That subset is: 'atomic', 'bool', 'buildtags', 'nilfunc', and
>   'printf'. You can see the documentation for these and other vet tests
>   via "go doc cmd/vet". To disable the running of go vet, use the
>   -vet=off flag."